# How to load pre-trained fastText model in gensim with .npy extension

Tags: gensim, pre-trained-model, fasttext

I am new to deep learning and I am trying to play with a pretrained word embedding model from a [paper](https://www.cse.iitb.ac.in/%7Epb/papers/sltu-ccurl20-il-we.pdf). I  downloaded the following files:

1)sa-d300-m2-fasttext.model

2)sa-d300-m2-fasttext.model.trainables.syn1neg.npy

3)sa-d300-m2-fasttext.model.trainables.vectors_ngrams_lockf.npy

4)sa-d300-m2-fasttext.model.wv.vectors.npy

5)sa-d300-m2-fasttext.model.wv.vectors_ngrams.npy

6)sa-d300-m2-fasttext.model.wv.vectors_vocab.npy

If in  case these details are needed
sa - sanskrit
d300 - embedding dimension
fastText - fastText

I dont have a prior experience with gensim, how can load the model into gensim or into tensorflow.

I tried

```
from gensim.models.wrappers import FastText
FastText.load_fasttext_format('/content/sa/300/fasttext/sa-d300-m2-fasttext.model.wv.vectors_ngrams.npy')
```

> FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/content/sa/300/fasttext/sa-d300-m2-fasttext.model.wv.vectors_ngrams.npy.bin'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That set of multiple files looks like it was saved from Gensim's FastText implementation, using Gensim's `save()` method - and thus is **not** in Facebook's original 'fasttext_format'.

So, try loading them with the following instead:

```py
from gensim.models.fasttext import FastText
model = FastText.load('/content/sa/300/fasttext/sa-d300-m2-fasttext.model')
```

(Upon loading that main/root file, it will find the subsidiary related files in the same directory, as long as they're all present.)

The source where you downloaded these files should have included clear instructions for loading them nearby!

Comment: I tried your suggestion but i got this error 'AttributeError: Can't get attribute 'FastTextKeyedVectors' on <module 'gensim.models.deprecated.keyedvectors' from '/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/gensim/models/deprecated/keyedvectors.py'>'

Comment: Now i am able to rectify the error i changed the import statement from                                       `from gensim.models.wrappers import FastText`                                                                    to `from gensim.models.fasttext import FastText`                                                                    But I am trying this in colab , the moment i loaded the model, 8 gb of gpu is used , is this normal

Comment: Yes, you'd want to use Gensim's Python `FastText`, not its (deprecated) wrapper around the external executable. (I've updated the answer to clearly use the right import, thanks.) The amount of memory needed will depend on the model, but it is also the case that the current (through `gensim-3.8.3`) implementation has some bugs that cause it to overuse RAM by a factor of 2 or more.